# Bitcoin Core v0.21 RPC credentials going bad

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I have tried to upgrade to bitcoin core 0.21 but things are not going good. I need some help.

I'm using Debian Buster.
I was using bitcoin core 0.20.1 before.

The folder locations are as I have in my config file:

```
dbbatchsize=4294967000
dbcache=12288
par=1 -daemon
server=1
maxtxfee=0.00002000
mintxfee=0.00000002

\# Options only for mainnet
[main]
conf=/media/WdElements/blockchain-backup/bitcoin.conf
datadir=/media/WdElements/blockchain-backup
debug=net
debug=rpc
debuglogfile=/media/WdElements/blockchain-backup/debug.log
addresstype=bech32
changetype=bech32
txindex=1
listen=1
```

When I start bitcoin daemon I see the [following output:](https://pastebin.com/kAtbvbuV)

```
2021-01-24T15:24:36Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from [::1]:34362
2021-01-24T15:24:36Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:36146
2021-01-24T15:24:41Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:36146
2021-01-24T15:24:41Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from [::1]:34362
2021-01-24T15:24:45Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from [::1]:34362
2021-01-24T15:24:45Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:36146
2021-01-24T15:24:49Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:36146
2021-01-24T15:24:49Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from [::1]:34362
2021-01-24T15:24:53Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from [::1]:34362
2021-01-24T15:24:53Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:36146
2021-01-24T15:24:58Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:36146
2021-01-24T15:24:58Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from [::1]:34362
2021-01-24T15:25:02Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from [::1]:34362
2021-01-24T15:25:02Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:36146
```

I already tried to generate my RPC credentials from `./share/rpcauth/` python plugin like this:

```
$ python3 rpcauth.py btc-user
String to be appended to bitcoin.conf:
rpcauth=btc-user:[REPLACEDHASH]
Your password:
[REPLACEDPSSWD]
```

and paste the first line into `bitcoin.conf`  like this:

```
dbbatchsize=4294967000
dbcache=12288
par=1 -daemon
server=1
rpcauth=btc-user:[REPLACEDHASH]
maxtxfee=0.00002000
mintxfee=0.00000002

\# Options only for mainnet
[main]
conf=/media/WdElements/blockchain-backup/bitcoin.conf
datadir=/media/WdElements/blockchain-backup
debug=net
debug=rpc
debuglogfile=/media/WdElements/blockchain-backup/debug.log
addresstype=bech32
changetype=bech32
txindex=1
listen=1
```

but I still get the same [error messages](https://pastebin.com/Tcd5Vwbr) when I start bitcoind as `bitcoind`:

```
2021-01-24T15:32:19Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from [::1]:35906
2021-01-24T15:32:19Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:37690
2021-01-24T15:32:23Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:37690
2021-01-24T15:32:23Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from [::1]:35906
2021-01-24T15:32:27Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from [::1]:35906
2021-01-24T15:32:27Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:37690
2021-01-24T15:32:31Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from [::1]:35906
2021-01-24T15:32:31Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:37690
2021-01-24T15:32:36Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:37690
2021-01-24T15:32:36Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from [::1]:35906
2021-01-24T15:32:40Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from [::1]:35906
2021-01-24T15:32:40Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:37690
2021-01-24T15:32:44Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from [::1]:35906
2021-01-24T15:32:44Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:37690
```

Anyone can help me figuring out what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: By *"crappy output"* do you mean the group of  `ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt` messages?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yes. I don't understand why it is outputting that error. I don't understand what coul possibly be wrong. I have a c-lightning node but it seems to be working just fine. I say this because I thought it could be trying to connect to bitcoin somehow using the RPC interface and it could not be authenticating correctly, but no, it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Seems similar to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62013801/477035) - not much help, I'm sorry.

Comment: Are you aware that the RPC cookie password will change every time bitcoind is started?

Comment: @Pseudonymous how come if I generated RPC credentials with a python plugin this last version of bitcoin core has and it tells to paste the generated credentials in bitcoin.conf?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I managed to find the culprit. It's actually an application I have running in the background that I simply completely forgot about it and it is trying to access to the RPC interface and as I have never paid too much attention to it, I think I never setup anything related to RPC in it. So, most probably that's the problem.

I used *netstat -p -at* and *ps -ef* to figure out what exactly was interacting with bitcoin core daemon.

Thanks every one. I think this one is solved.
Psy